# Does an external pointer reference to a field of a deleted struct makes the pointer refers to garbage values in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, reference

I have a fundamental doubt regarding struct deallocation and pointer usage in C++.

Suppose I have the following scenario:

```
...
struct B
{
    ...
    struct A a_field;
    ...
}
...
struct A* a_ref;
vector<struct B> b_vec;
...
// populate, use and modify b_vec elements here
...
a_ref = &(b_vec[i].a_field); // can be a one-time assignment
...
// deallocate b_vec elements here (including b_vec[i]) here
...
// using a_ref->some_field here !?!
...
```

Is `a_ref` still going to point to the last modified state of the `a_field` of `b_vec[i]`, making it reliable for use later?

Or is C++-STL deallocation going to make all the fields of `b_vec[i]` unreliable (garbage value) when it pushes it out of the vector?

Comment: 1) C++ doesn't have a garbage collector. 2) If you hold a pointer to a vector element and the vector is destroyed then your pointer is now dangling. Dereferencing the pointer is undefined behavior and a terrible bug.

Comment: Oh, pardon my unawareness about the garbage collection part.
I expected some sort of implicit reference counting to memory blocks which could protect it from dangling scenarios.
But I understand what you are saying. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you were actually asking about C# (which has garbage collector)? Also note that in C++ pointers and references are two separate concepts, so `a_ref` is not actually a reference.

Comment: I was working on some C++ code when I got this doubt (thankfully not an error yet which I certainly would have at some point).
I haven't really worked on C# as of yet but it would be nice to know the situation there.

Comment: Yes, @VTT. I am aware about the conceptual difference between pointers and references in C++. And also understanding that `a_ref` was indeed a pointer according to my question. Thanks for pointing that out. I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you hold a pointer to a `std::vector` element that pointer can be invalidated several ways. For example, if the `std::vector` is destroyed or if the `std::vector` needs to reallocate memory when it grows.

Dereferencing a dangling pointer is undefined behavior. It's a logic error and must be avoided.